# Remove specific packages from internal apt repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, apt-mirror

I have created an internal apt repository using apt-mirror. I need to remove only certain packages (source, lucid) from the repo.

I have attempted to use the clean.sh script to do this, but it only wants to remove outdated packages. I have removed the deb lines from mirror.list so apt-mirror is not pulling new packages for source and lucid, but I cannot find a way to remove the old ones in the pool directory. Short of deleting my entire repository and doing a fresh mirror, what are my options?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you should be able to set certain packages to never install by creating an entry for each package in /etc/apt/preferences or by creating a file in /etc/apt/preferences.d https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#A.2Fetc.2Fapt.2Fpreferences

Comment: google "apt-pinning" for more info, replace the * with the package names you would want to block and make sure to use a number that suits your purpose.